The release apk does not work when built with `--target-platform` option
There are two possibilities to create apk for arm64 (at least that's what we need to find out):
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64

or
flutter build apk --split-per-abi (then use app-arm64-v8a-release.apk)

For some reason in the first case I can not install the generated app-release.apk
Aren't these the same options to build apk for arm64?
